# Zend FW1 in netbeans ->1 Uncaught exception 'Invalid controller specified (index.php)'

Tags: php, netbeans, zend-framework, wamp

I have a legacy project with ZF1 and ZF as a library under/library/ folder.
Running it locally on WAMP at D:\WAMP\www\prj.local\
(important to note, when I use JetBrains' PHPStorm, it runs the project exactly like it runs on production web server? with no any additional set ups)

**Netbeans 8.1 Project settings:**

- Project folder: `D:\WAMP\www\prj.local`
- Source Folder: `D:\WAMP\www\prj.local`
- Run configuration: `http://prj.local/` (properly set, so I can type it from browser and it will run the project... but I need to debug it!)
- Index File: `public_html/index.php`
- Advanced Settings:

  - Server Path: `http://prj.local/`,
  - Project Path: `D:\WAMP\www\prj.local\public_html\`
- Folders structure:

[image: Folders structure]

When I run it under NetBeans 8.1 I have the following error.

- 1 Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (index.php)' in D:\wamp\www\dupcheck.local\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php:248
- **Important to note** - when I run the same project via JetBrains' PHPStorm, everything works as it should, with no extra settings. Unfortunately, the license is to expire very soon.

Does somebody have an

Comment: Try changing Index File: "public_html/index.php" to "index.php"

Comment: did not work :)

Comment: Try changing Index File: "public_html/index.php" to ""